# When does a return statement break a function?

Tags: c++

I'm getting "control reaches end of non-void function" with this code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> solutions;
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = i+1; j < nums.size(); i++)
            {
                if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target)
                {
                    solutions.push_back(j);
                    solutions.push_back(i);
                    return solutions:
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I thought a return statement was supposed to break a function as soon as it's reached? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What should it return when no solution is found?

Comment: Any reason you are returning a vector that is already part of that class? What if you call the function multiple times?

Comment: @PaulRooney, A copy is being returned.

Comment: In the second *for* loop maybe you want `j++` instead of `i++`.

Comment: @chris sure but the second time its called its potentially gonna contain 4 items. Plus he could save the copy by having the vector be local and use RVO.

Comment: unless of course the maintenance of state is intentional. In which case I withdraw my comment.

Comment: @PaulRooney Yeah, I mistook your comment then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the return type of your function is a vector It must always return a vector. But you have written your code in a way that it may not always return vector. if your `if` statement never becomes true then function returns void by definition it must return vector. that's why compiler may generate warning. I guess following will fix your issue:

```
vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = i+1; j < nums.size(); j++)
            {
                if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target)
                {
                    solutions.push_back(j);
                    solutions.push_back(i);
                    return solutions; 
                }
            }
        }
        return solutions;
    }
```

Comment: This is an easy case for multiple return statements being much clearer.

Comment: @chris ok...I'm updating my solution based on your comment.

Comment: @Asif That makes sense - thanks! Just out of curiosity, if for some reason I can assume that the if statement is always true, would the code be fine?

Comment: @jzhao code is actually okk if you assume that. That's why compiler generates warning not error to inform you it might have missed the case.

Comment: Honesly, I'd go for `return {j, i};` and `return {};` respectively, but it's kind of nitpicky at that point.

Comment: Actually, that messes with the class state. Interesting that such state is kept 2 ints per function call.

Comment: Going to face bad things if you (and the OP) don't fix the second for loop: `i++` should be `j++`.

Comment: @skypjack I just copied his code... didn't see parts which are not that relevant..editing now..thanx :)